# How to edit the '<-- older' link on archive page in Blankslate theme?

Tags: posts, archives, previous-post-link

I am using the 'Blankslate' theme for Wordpress and I edited about everything except for the older and newer links on my blog page.

How can I change this links in the Blankslate theme? It isn't located in the function.php and index.php files.

Comment: This is a little too specific to the theme. Can you not determine _how_ is it added at all? Is there a hook or template part call around there in templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong then i think you are talking about this [Blankslate theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate).

If this is the case then you can edit the older and newer links displayed on archive page by editing the following code by overwriting the theme file nav-below.php in the [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

```
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(sprintf( __( '%s older', 'blankslate' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>' ) ) ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(sprintf( __( 'newer %s', 'blankslate' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) ?></div>
```

Comment: Ah, it's located in the nav-below.php files. Thanks. I just realized that it could be there.